# How to convert SOCK_DGRAM to SOCK_RAW?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, rtp

I'm working on an open source where SOCK_DGRAM is used to send RTP packets.

Like this:

```
 int sock = socket(af, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

But i'm supposed to use the same socket as SOCK_RAW to send the UDP packets that i prepare.

Is this possible to convert the UDP socket to RAW socket?

if it is possible how it can be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `SOCK_RAW` while creating the socket. why'd you need the `same` socket anyway?

Comment: and remember, while using `SOCK_RAW`, you'll not get any _help_ for your packet header. [L3/L4]. You have to take care of that yourself.

Comment: because i'm supposed to use the same source address to send the packets. otherwise the packets will be ignored

Comment: You don't need to use a raw socket to get a consistent source address. Your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you said `need to use same socket`, otherwise, you can follow the below steps to transfer packet over `RAW` socket.

1. create the `socket` using `SOCK_RAW`.
2. define and populate the IP header [`struct ipheader`]
3. define and populate the UDP header [`struct udphdr`]
4. set the socket for not to use a system (kernel) provied header [`setsockopt()` for `IP_HDRINCL`as `1`]
5. send the buffer [`sendto()`]

You can find some nice tutorials (and maybe some sample codes, too) [here](http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html).

Comment: Because i'm supposed to send the packets from the same source

Comment: and what do you mean by `source`? IP & port, right? That's in your control with `RAW` . :-)

Comment: nope!! that comes dynamically when session is established

Comment: is it? interesting !!! BTW, did you check the link I provided for sample implementation [and most importantly, the packet forming and sending part] of RAW socket?

Comment: It's a sip protocol, When invite request comes, my proxy will allocate one port and change the SDP. likewise it does it for 200 ok. so the packet transmission will happen between those two allocated ports.

Comment: Now i couldnt catch the port that is allocated dynamically. That is why i'm trying to use the same socket

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understood you [and `SIP`], but I see no reson for not knowing the `destination port number of an incoming packet` for which you'll be sending the reply. please enlight me.

Comment: if we made a call we will be getting the SDP, if the sdp has private ip and port my proxy will allocate one ip and port for that request. so further if you want to send packets you can send to the public address and from there it will reach actual address whatever had come along with initial request